# how to create an android app that has admin having rights to view , alter all databases and which require admin permission for successful signup

Tags: android, admin

admin will decide what data to be visible to specific person. Eg managing different user accounts and sharing the profiles of users according to requirement. and where to store database so that data base can be fetched by normal user as well as admin

Comment: Android's security model does not support any such thing - databases private to apps are controlled by those that own them and other apps on the device are denied access by design, so this idea will go nowhere unless you first hack android to break the security model.  Meanwhile remote databases would be secured to whatever degree their servers are configured to.

Comment: Where are these databases hosted? On your server or on the phone? If they're on the phone, Do they all belong to the same app or as you asking about restricting/viewing access to other apps databases? Question is very broad.

Comment: specific user can see his account as well as other person`s some details. there are 2 use cases type a and b so type a users can view their  own profile and logs as well as type b few details. and vice versa for b

Answer (score 0):

Typically you need to build all of this on a server, make a webservice to sync data between devices... not a tiny thing !

Comment: can i also go for cloud console for maintaining all database and gcm for giving permisission for logins and communication purposes???

Comment: Never done that except by my own means :) but indeed Google offers a lot of tools, won't be able to give any advice here...